# Does $f$ belong to $W^{1,p}(\mathbf{R})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, improper-integrals, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I have to prove that $$f(x)=\frac1{(1+x^2)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\ln(2+x^2)}, \ \ \ 0<\alpha<1$$ belongs to $W^{1,p}(\mathbf{R})$ for $p\in[\frac1{\alpha},\infty]$ and that it does not belong to $L^p$ for $p\in[1,\frac1{\alpha})$.

Since $f$ is even and positive I can only discute the convergence of this integral $$\int_2^\infty f(x)^p dx.$$ $f$ is defined on the whole real line, so I need only to discute its behaviour at $\infty$.

But I have that $$f(x)\sim \frac1{(x^2)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\ln(x^2)}=\frac1{2x^\alpha\ln(x)}$$ therefore $$\int_2^\infty f(x)^p dx\sim\frac12\int_2^\infty\frac1{x^{\alpha p}\ln^p(x)} dx.$$

Since the last integral converges iff $\alpha p\ge1$, I can assert that $$f\in L^p(\mathbf{R})\Leftrightarrow p\in[\frac1{\alpha},\infty].$$

Am I wrong?
And, now, I could I prove that $f\in W^{1,p}(\mathbf{R})$ for such $p$?

Comment: For the belonging of $f$ to $W^{1,p} (\mathbb{R})$ you have to check that the weak derivative of $f$ is $L^p$-integrable (and for which $p$s).

Comment: Is the weak derivative equal to the standard one?

Comment: This is something for you to check; either you can play around with the computations and see where they lead you or you can use some sufficient conditions, for example in Burenkov - Sobolev Spaces on Domains, lemma 1 page 19 (spoiler: if a function on an open domain has ordinary continuous directional derivative, then it will coincide with the weak - but check some book for the precise details).